# Regular expressions: Replace a text variable and the number in brackets with a matching dict entry

Tags: python, regex

I want to replace in a c++ source code file an array variable with a function.
Additionally, I need to replace the hardcoded number with an enum.
For this, I thought to use regular expressions and a dict. The dict represents the number to enum associations.

This is the example code which I want to transform with the python script:

```
int a = foo[0];
int b = foo[1];
int c = foo[2];
```

This is the desired result after transformation:

```
int a = bar(enum_zero);
int b = bar(enum_one);
int c = bar(enum_two);
```

Python dictionary for enum replacement:

```
enums = dict([('zero',0),
              ('one', 1),
              ('two', 2)])
```

This is the current non-working which can replace the array with the function, but not the number with the enum:

```
import fileinput
import re

enums = dict([('zero',0),
              ('one', 1),
              ('two', 2)])

search = r'foo'
replace = r'bar'

read = open('test.cpp', 'r')
write = open('out.cpp', 'w')

for line in read:
    if line.find(search) != -1:
        s_tag = r'(\-)('+search+r')\[(\d+)\](?=\.\w+)'
        r_tag = r'\1'+replace+r'(\3)'
        line = re.sub(s_tag, r_tag, line, re.M)
        write.write(line)
    else:
        write.write(line)

read.close()
```

Comment: I want to transform the "example code" to "Desired code"

Answer (score 2):

This can all be done using a single `re.sub()` call as follows:

```
import re

search = r'foo'
replace = r'bar'    
s_tag = r'\b(' + search + r') *?\[ *?(\d+) *?\]'
enums = {'0':'enum_zero', '1':'enum_one', '2':'enum_two'}

with open('test.cpp') as f_cpp:
    text = f_cpp.read()

with open('out.cpp', 'w') as f_out:    
    f_out.write(re.sub(s_tag, lambda x: "{}({})".format(replace, enums[x.group(2)]), text))
```

Giving you an output file of:

```
int a = bar(enum_zero);
int b = bar(enum_one);
int c = bar(enum_two);
```

It uses a lambda function to look up the required substitution using the `enums` dictionary and format the output into suitable function call format.

Using a `with` also means there is no need to explicitly close the file afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

It might simplify things if you change your dictionary and use groups():

```
import fileinput
import re

replacements = {0: 'zero', 1: 'one', 2: 'two'}

variable = r'foo'
function = r'bar'

read = open('test.cpp', 'r')
write = open('out.cpp', 'w')

for line in read:
    m = re.match(r'(.*)' + variable + r'\[(\d+)]', line)
    if m:
        start, key = m.groups()
        modified = '{start}{function}({replacement});\n'.format(
            start=start,
            function=function,
            replacement=replacements[int(key)]
        )
        write.write(modified)
    else:
        write.write(line)

read.close()
```